# Return substring before and after a certain word

Tags: substring

I have a column with large volumes of text in each record. I need to search for a certain word and return the 50 characters before the word and 50 characters after the word. I'm using substring to return the characters after, but can't find a way to return the characters before the word.

`substring(RepText,(PATINDEX('certainword',RepText),50)` works great for returning text after 'certainword', but not before the word.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: And what's your language?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, which prints 2 letters before and after the word sub

```
declare @st varchar(100) ='test subis good'
select PATINDEX('%sub%', @st)
select SUBSTRING(@st, PATINDEX('%sub%', @st) + LEN('sub'), 2),
SUBSTRING(@st, PATINDEX('%sub%', @st) - ( case when len(@st) < 2 then len(@st) else 2 end), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? If this helps, please up vote my answer so I can get lots of points and look cool :)

```
if schema_id(N'utility') is null
  execute (N'create schema utility');
go
if object_id(N'[utility].[get_some]'
         , N'TF') is not null
drop function [utility].[get_some];
go
/*
select [lead], [lag] from [utility].[get_some] (N'return_abcdeandabcde_this', N'and', 5, 5);
select [lead], [lag] from [utility].[get_some] (N'return_a c eanda c e_this', N'and', 5, 5);
select [lead], [lag] from [utility].[get_some] (N'return_ bcd and bcd _this', N'and', 5, 5);
*/
create function [utility].[get_some] (
@input         [nvarchar](max)
, @search      [nvarchar](max)
, @lead_length [int]
, @lag_length  [int])
returns @data table (
[lead]  [nvarchar](max)
, [lag] [nvarchar](max))
as
begin
  insert into @data
              ([lead],[lag])
    select substring(@input
                     , charindex(@search
                                 , @input) - @lead_length
                     , @lead_length)  as [lead]
           , substring(@input
                       , charindex(@search, @input) + len(@search)
                       , @lag_length) as [lag];
  return;
end;
```

go